# Display turns on at midnight?

Tags: battery, screen

Every day at midnight the display on my tablet (Asus Transforer TF101 ICS) turns on for a few seconds.  Ordinarily, this wouldn't be a big deal, but I am using the [Screebl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keyes.screebl.full&hl=en) application, which keeps the tablet awake when it's vertical.  Thus, the device turns on in my bag and then never goes to sleep, draining the battery.

Is there a way to find out what application (or system component) is waking the device up at midnight, and how does one stop this behavior?

Comment: Hmm, if it drains battery then one easy way to check would be to let it drain and see what what application drained your battery from battery status.

Comment: @roxan It's not the application that's draining the battery, but the screen.

Comment: converted to an answer...

Answer (score 1):

try to trigger it manually.

Root reqired:
Install BetterBatteryStats to view 'alarms', aka programmed low level device wakeups (you can find a free .apk on xda here, search for 'Attached' http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809 ). set your clock just before midnight and reset bbs' logs.

If you can trigger it, you should see which app has caused a wakeup in BBS' log.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After turning off the network time, I set it back manually and then it didn't turn on the screen at midnight.